# Setting up my downloaded font to bold

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, label

I have a label displaying a title in a view, I'm trying to setup my font to bold, I've downloaded and installed this font, it isn't a default font like some fonts that are included in xCode I've tried with some methods but isn't work just work with the default fonts so I want to know if there's a method that I could work with to make this possible, the font that I downloaded and installed is "Gotham Rounded

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the bold version of your font?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your TTF file is added as an embedded resource in your project and its entry is also added in `.plist` file under supported fonts key `Fonts provided by application`.

Also your TTF should have the bold interface as well to support bold font display.